# How to get my checkbox loop to update each checkbox individually instead of both of them in php and mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, mysqli

I can get the checkboxes to update but they aren’t working exactly right.  When both boxes are empty I can check either one of them and both boxes get updated to checked.  If both boxes are checked I have to uncheck both boxes for them to be updated to unchecked.  I can’t get one box to be checked and the other to be unchecked.

Any ideas?

I really appreciate your help.

mySQL Tabel

```
 id | departments_fk | qsps_fk | visible
270 |             1  |    218  |     1
271 |            22  |    218  |     0
272 |             1  |    219  |     0
273 |            22  |    219  |     1
274 |             1  |    220  |     1
275 |            22  |    220  |     1
```

HTML Code

```
<form action="edit-qsps.php?qspName=<?php echo $current_qsp["id"]; ?>" method="post">

<div class="qsp-name">QSP Name:

<input type="text" name="qsp_name" class="name-box" value="<?php echo $current_qsp["qsp_name"]; ?>" />

 </div>


 <div class="rev">QSP Rev:

 <input type="text" name="qsp_rev" class="rev-box" value="<?php echo $current_qsp["qsp_rev"]; ?>" />

 </div>

 <div class="qsp-departments">Department:</div>

 <?php
     global $db_connection;
     global $department_checked;
     global $current_qsp;
     global $id_department;

     echo "<ul>";

        $qsp_department_list = find_all_departments();
        $department['id'] = $id_department;

       while($department = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qsp_department_list)) {

            echo  htmlentities($department['department_name']);
            echo " : ";

            $qsp_department_checks = find_all_checks_for_department($current_qsp['id']);
            $checks = $department_checked;

            global $department_checked;

                while($checks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qsp_department_checks)) {

                    if ($current_qsp['id'] == $checks['qsps_fk'] && $checks['departments_fk'] == $department['id']) {

                    echo "<div class='department-checked'>";            
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='hidden-checkBoxes[]' value='";
                    echo htmlentities($checks['departments_fk']);
                    echo "' />";
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='department-checkBoxes[]' value='";
                    echo htmlentities($checks['departments_fk']);
                    echo "' ";

                        if($checks['checked'] == '1'){
                            echo "checked='checked'";
                        }
                    echo " />";

                    echo "</label>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    } 
                }   
            mysqli_free_result($qsp_department_checks);
            }
        mysqli_free_result($qsp_department_list);
        echo "</ul>";
        ?>

    <div class="create-btn">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE QSP" />
</div>
</form>
```

PHP Process Code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    global $db_connection;
    global $id_department;


    $id_qsp = $current_qsp["id"];
    $qsp_name = mysql_prep($_POST["qsp_name"]);
    $qsp_rev = mysql_prep($_POST["qsp_rev"]);

    $query1  = "UPDATE qsps SET ";
    $query1 .= "qsp_name = '{$qsp_name}', ";
    $query1 .= "qsp_rev = '{$qsp_rev}' ";
    $query1 .= "WHERE id = {$id_qsp} ";
    $query1 .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query1);


        foreach($_POST['hidden-checkBoxes'] as $checked) {  
            if (isset($_POST['department-checkBoxes'])) {
                $val = 1;
            } else {
                $val = 0;
            }

            $query2 = "UPDATE junction_departments_qsps SET ";
            $query2 .= "checked = {$val} ";
            $query2 .= "WHERE departments_fk = {$checked} ";
            $query2 .= "AND qsps_fk = {$id_qsp} ";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query2);               
        }


        redirect_to("edit-qsps.php");
    } else {
        // Failure
        $message = "Employee Update Failed.";
    }

?>
```

Updated Process Code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
global $db_connection;
global $id_department;

    $id_qsp = $current_qsp["id"];
    $qsp_name = mysql_prep($_POST["qsp_name"]);
    $qsp_rev = mysql_prep($_POST["qsp_rev"]);

    $query1  = "UPDATE qsps SET ";
    $query1 .= "qsp_name = '{$qsp_name}', ";
    $query1 .= "qsp_rev = '{$qsp_rev}' ";
    $query1 .= "WHERE id = {$id_qsp} ";
    $query1 .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query1);


        if(!empty($_POST['department-checkBoxes'])) {
            foreach($_POST['department-checkBoxes'] as $check) {

             echo $check;
            //only checked checkboxes come to $POST
            $query2 = "UPDATE junction_departments_qsps SET ";
            $query2 .= "checked = 1 ";
            $query2 .= "WHERE departments_fk = {$check} ";
            $query2 .= "AND qsps_fk = {$id_qsp} ";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query2); 
            }           
        }

        redirect_to("edit-qsps.php");
    } else {
        // Failure
        $message = "Employee Update Failed.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form

```
<form action="edit-qsps.php?qspName=<?php echo $current_qsp["id"]; ?>" method="post">
      <div class="qsp-name">QSP Name:
        <input type="text" name="qsp_name" class="name-box" value="<?php echo $current_qsp["qsp_name"]; ?>" />
      </div>

    <div class="rev">QSP Rev:
        <input type="text" name="qsp_rev" class="rev-box" value="<?php echo $current_qsp["qsp_rev"]; ?>" />
      </div>

        <div class="qsp-departments">Department:</div>
        <?php
        global $db_connection;
        global $current_qsp;

        echo "<ul>";

        $qsp_department_list = find_all_departments();

        while($department = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qsp_department_list)) {

            echo  htmlentities($department['department_name']);
            echo " : ";

            $qsp_department_checks = find_all_checks_for_department($current_qsp['id']);

                while($checks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qsp_department_checks)) {

                    $id_checked = htmlentities($checks['id']);

                    if ($current_qsp['id'] == $checks['qsps_fk'] && $checks['departments_fk'] == $department['id']) {

                        echo "<div class='department-checked'>";            

                        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='hidden-checkBoxes[]' value='";
                        echo htmlentities($checks['id']);
                        echo "' style='display:none' checked='checked' />";

                        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='department-checkBoxes[]' value='";
                        echo htmlentities($checks['id']);
                        echo "' ";

                        if($checks['checked'] == '1'){
                            echo "checked='checked'";
                        }
                        echo " />";                             

                        echo "</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    } 
                }   
            mysqli_free_result($qsp_department_checks);
            }
        mysqli_free_result($qsp_department_list);
        echo "</ul>";

        ?>

        <div class="employee-category">Employee Category:</div>
        <?php echo edit_employee_category_checkBoxes(); ?>

     <div class="create-btn">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE QSP" />
     </div>
    </form>
```

PHP Processing Code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
global $db_connection;

    $id_qsp = $current_qsp["id"];
    $qsp_name = mysql_prep($_POST["qsp_name"]);
    $qsp_rev = mysql_prep($_POST["qsp_rev"]);

    $query1  = "UPDATE qsps SET ";
    $query1 .= "qsp_name = '{$qsp_name}', ";
    $query1 .= "qsp_rev = '{$qsp_rev}' ";
    $query1 .= "WHERE id = {$id_qsp} ";
    $query1 .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query1);

    $departments_id = $_POST["hidden-checkBoxes"];
    $hidden_depart = $_POST["department-checkBoxes"];

    if(isset($_POST['hidden-checkBoxes'])) {

        foreach ($departments_id as $depart_id){ 

        $visible_check = in_array($depart_id, $hidden_depart) ? 1 : 0;

            $query2 = "UPDATE junction_departments_qsps SET ";
            $query2 .= "checked = {$visible_check} ";
            $query2 .= "WHERE id = {$depart_id} ";

            $result2 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query2); 
            }   
    }

        redirect_to("edit-qsps.php");
    } else {
        // Failure
        $message = "Employee Update Failed.";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the 'department-checkBoxes'. Now you are not getting their values, just checking if entire POST variable is set.

```
if(!empty($_POST['department-checkBoxes'])) {
    foreach($_POST['department-checkBoxes'] as $check) {

     echo $check;
    //only checked checkboxes come to $POST
    $query2 = "UPDATE junction_departments_qsps SET ";
    $query2 .= "checked = 1 ";
    $query2 .= "WHERE departments_fk = {$checked} ";
    $query2 .= "AND qsps_fk = {$id_qsp} ";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query2); 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to use this code.  Do use it in my process code or in the form?  Do I need to run a second query if used in the process code?  Would I use this after I do the first foreach loop and query?

Comment: insided the for do your normal update. only checked checkboxes will be in the $_POST.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: please paste your latest code and specify what is the issue

Comment: Hi Aris I added my code above.  The data base doesn't seem to be updating at all.  When in my original code it at least updated both checkboxes.  Thank you.

Comment: what does echo $check; print?

Comment: Nothing from what I can tell.  Where would I see the evidence of the echo $check working?

Comment: it should print something on the screen. change it to echo "check=$check";